# Georgian dumplings (khinkali) sticking to the bottom of the pot

Tags: meat, dough, boiling, dumplings

Khinkali are boiled meat dumplings from the Georgian cuisine. They're formed putting about a spoonful of ground pork+beef meat with water and spices in the center of a few millimeters thick dough disk which is then sealed perfectly with a number of folds that depend on the ability of the cook and then cooked into boiling water until they float.
The dough contains water, flour, egg and salt.

Rolling the dough disks it happens that some flour gets on it, especially when the disks are prepared beforehand. Of course, a way to prevent them from sticking to each other in the pot would be not to cook too many at a time, but how can the excess flour on the exterior surface affect their possible sticking to the bottom of the pot?

The consequences of this would be of course breaking and losing the inside juice that is part of their eating experience.

Comment: How deep is the pot of water you are boiling the dumplings in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the additional flour as the cause. It's there to prevent them sticking during manufacture & once in the pan will in seconds just be 'more dough'.

I see several ways to mitigate their sticking...

- Bigger pan - obvious, but there's a reason your pasta pan is the biggest one in the kitchen.
- Drop them a few at a time, so they don't touch until the outside has had a chance to start cooking.
- Non-stick pan - at least then they can only stick to each other.
- Keep them moving all the time - gentle persuasion is always a good idea, rather than having to prise them apart afterwards.
- Add some oil to the water - pasta trick, ostensibly to prevent the water boiling over, but does very slightly coat the surface if you stir.

Comment: The second point is the key - keeping the water hot enough that they cook on the outside before they touch the bottom/other dumplings is essential. To do this use a big pot with lots of water at a rolling boil and stir it before adding the dumplings, so that they spend a bit longer in suspension (and cooking) before hitting the bottom